# The dev server never responds when starting an empty project based on NextJs documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Based on [NextJs framework documentation](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/getting-started/setup), I followed some setup steps to run an empty project :

```
mkdir hello-next
cd hello-next
npm init -y
npm install --save react react-dom next
mkdir pages
```

Then I added these 3 lines to my `package.json` file :

```
 "scripts": {
   "dev": "next",
   "build": "next build",
   "start": "next start"
 }
```

So right now everything should be ready to make my app run, executing this command line :

```
npm run dev
```

But I always get in an *endless loading loop* on `http://localhost:3000`.

on my console output :

```
[ wait ]  starting the development server ...
[ info ]  waiting on http://localhost:3000 ...
[ ready ] compiled successfully (ready on http://localhost:3000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it doesn't work like the tutorial suggests. I opened [an issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/7857) in the Next Github repository *which is now resolved and a fix should be available in the 9.0.1 release.*

In the meantime, you can add a simple page by creating a file named `index.js` or `index.jsx` in the `pages` directory and restarting the server.

```
// pages/index.js
export default () => 'Super simple page';
```

Then, navigating to `http://localhost:3000` should show this page and any other path should show the default Next's 404 error page.